# Colors VS Screens - Colors to avoid

Tags: color, contrast, displays

I'm working on my personal webpage, my primary background color (apart from white) is straight-forward turquoise (#40e0d0) from the styles selection in my navigator.

On my laptop, the color is more green-ish than blue, and specially comfortable to the eyes, but in all other screens I'm trying it becomes more blue-ish and kind of (sometimes very) bleeding and fluorescent. I know every screen is different and that it also depends on the settings, but all these screens are reasonably set up in brilliance and contrast.

I'm starting to suspect that some colors should be avoided and I wanted to ask if there is any dogma around this issue, considering it "is" an issue.

I found the info in this other [thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38334/what-is-a-good-color-combination-visibility-for-outside-use/38337#38337) quite useful,but it doesn't quite answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is *some* history of "[web safe colors](https://websafecolors.info/learn)" which you can read about, but essentially there's no real color to avoid.

If you want true color accuracy, you need a screen that will act as a "source of truth". There's no way to really do that without a physical [calibration tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055MBQOW), but you can try your best with what you have using [guides like these](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/) on your existing hardware/software setup.

Once you've done that, you can pick a color that you want, but keep in mind that the majority of displays will be **close** to what you see, especially given different lighting conditions and night-shift apps.

Having said that, at the very minimum, you need to [make sure your contrast ratios are good](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/), as that doesn't care about colors.